# Are "out of the row" fields read when a clustered index is used?

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustered-index, varchar

I know that when `VARCHAR(MAX)/NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns are used the data is stored `out of the row` - the data row will have a pointer to another location where the 'large value' is stored.

I have the following questions:

1. Is each field stored `out of the row` or only the `max` ones?
2. If you are using the `clustered index` of the table to read the whole record, are fields that are stored out of the row read, too?

> VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) is considered as a 'large value type'. Large value types are usually stored 'out of  row'. It means that the ...

Comment: Where did that last quoted bit come from? It is not correct.

Comment: @PaulWhite http://stackoverflow.com/a/148465/1080354

Comment: The full text in the original MSDN thread (by Jacob Sebastian) is correct. The Stack Overflow "quote" loses quite a bit of that. The small fraction of that you quoted above omits all the important bits :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *I know that when `VARCHAR(MAX)/NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns are used the data is stored out of the row...*

Actually, that depends on the setting of the `large value types out of row` option, which can be set using `sp_tableoption`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173530.aspx):

[image: BOL extract]

The **default** is for `MAX` values to be stored **in-row**, up to 8000 bytes, if they fit. Unless you have used `sp_tableoption` to change the default, your `MAX` data will most likely be stored in-row.

That said, it is poor practice to use `MAX` data types for values that will never exceed 8000 bytes - use a non-MAX type instead. Aside from anything else, performance is often significantly poorer when dealing with `MAX` types, because SQL Server must be prepared to cope with data that might be up to 2GB in size.

> *Is each field stored out of the row or only the max ones?*

Only the `MAX` ones. In addition, if a previously in-row `MAX` column is moved off-row, only that column in that row is affected. It is replaced in-row by a pointer to the off-row `LOB` structure. [There are also circumstances where non-MAX columns may be moved off-row.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/19/i-see-no-lobs.aspx)

> *If you are using the clustered index of the table to read the whole record, are fields that are stored out of the row read, too?*

Scanning the clustered index traverses only in-row data. If off-row data is needed for the query, it is looked up using the in-row pointer.

Comment: Is this always true - `Scanning the clustered index traverses only in-row data.`? For example, if you want do display the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field values how is it possible to work only with the `in-row-data` (if the values are stored out of the row)? Or when you are using the clustered index (because there is no covering index) but you are not going to `work` with the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field the SQL Server is clever enough to see that and skip the look up to `out-of-row` data?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, finally, if you have two columns - `int` and `nvarchar(max)` and you are selecting only the `int` column, the SQL-Server does not waste resource to `read` the `out-of-row` data as it knows you are not going to use it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very nice. Seems, that using the `sp_tableoption` you are able to put out of the table everything that is not often used in order to reduce the size of the row, when a lot of clustered index seeks/scans are made.

Comment: @gotqn Yes. Off-row was the default for the old LOB types `text`, `ntext` and `image`. You could also store the large types in a separate table, of course.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior for large objects storage can be controlled by the table setting:

`exec sp_tableoption N'MyTable', 'large value types out of row', <'ON' or 'OFF'>`

The reference in the SQL Server 2012 documentation is at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173530.aspx

Therefore you can control where the space is used, in-row or stored out of row.

Comment: Thanks, I really did not know that you are able to control this.